# How do I make computed fields visible when other fields are presented?

Tags: entities

I have been spinning my wheels for hours.  I added a computed field to a content type and it simply wouldn't show up in the result.  I made an all new content type with nothing in it and the computed field showed up fine.  Once I added an additional field, the computed field vanished.  Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1):

No reason why it shouldn't show up just because there are other fields in that content type. Are you sure there is data to show?

Comment: Yes, I even hard-coded it to return "xxxxxx".  It works fine with my test:

    $entity_field[0]['value'] = "xxxx";

Comment: I think my issue was that I wasn't editing my content after changing the type.  After I went to an edit screen and then saved (even if not doing anything), then they showed up.  Thanks